# I can't find my Bashrc file?

Tags: linux, bash, parrotsec

[![I don't know why, but I don't seem to have a .bashrc file? I'm running parrot OS on virtual-box. I've also tried going into /etc/skel/ and looking for a bashrc file there too, but no luck. Does anyone know how to fix this?[image: Default Parrot Terminal]

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a general rule one shouldn't post textual output as image, but copy-paste the actual text itself, surrounded by the code brackets ('{ }'). I'd recommend checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how these sites work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just make it if you want it and it wasn't created on install from /etc/skel or comparable:

```
touch .bashrc
```

then open it, edit it to add whatever you want, then save it, then:

```
source .bashrc
```

to set it active in your login session.

It's just a file with defaults for your user/session, there's nothing special about it except I think the file name. I don't know where that is stored for autoload, Parrot if I remember right is Debian based, so it should be roughly the same as Debian.

To confirm it loads with login after testing it, logout, and test again with whatever changes you made.

Sample .bashrc:

```
[ -f /etc/profile ] && . /etc/profile
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PATH=$PATH:/sbin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin
export EDITOR=/bin/nano
alias ccc='curl 192.168.1.12 -v -I'
```

[added alias sample, where alias name is ccc.]

Comment: Great, Thanks. Also, how would I create an alias for "cURL (IP) -v -I".

Comment: added alias sample. Adding alias is easy way to test it is all workings since if the alias works, it's working. The command is curl, not cURL, but that's how you do it.